# Can turn on WiFi programatically but can't turn it off

Tags: android, debugging

So I searched how to switch the wifi state programatically in Android, and I found this:

```
                case R.id.drawer_item1:
                    Intent i;

                        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);


                    break;
                case R.id.drawer_item2:

                    wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

                    break;
```

This actually works for turning the WiFi on, but I can't turn it off.

This is my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Anyone got any ideas but might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: try using same instance of wifiManager for both turning on and OFF .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because you should use same object (`WifiManager` reference) in both cases (on/off) like this:

```
            case R.id.drawer_item1:
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                break;
            case R.id.drawer_item2:
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                break;
```

and define your object as global object:

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```